# Get all min values from dictionary list

Tags: python

I have the following snippet:

```
list = [{"num":1,"test":"A"},{"num":6,"test":"B"},{"num":5,"test":"c"},{"num":1,"test":"D"}]
min = None
for x in list:
    if x["num"]<min or min==None:
        min=x["num"]
print(min)
print([index for index, element in enumerate(list) 
                      if min == element["num"]])
```

Which doesn't really output anything useful, my objective was to output, as said in the title, the dictionaries with "1" in `num`.

A noob question I know, but this is my first contact with the language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) takes a `key` argument that lets you specific how to calculate the min. This will let you find an object with the min `num` value. You can then use that to find all of them with a list comprehension (or similar method).

```
l = [{"num":1,"test":"A"},{"num":6,"test":"B"},{"num":5,"test":"c"},{"num":1,"test":"D"}]

m = min(l, key=lambda d: d['num'])
# {'num': 1, 'test': 'A'}

[item for item in l if item['num'] == m['num']]
# [{'num': 1, 'test': 'A'}, {'num': 1, 'test': 'D'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
list_=[{"num":1,"test":"A"},{"num":6,"test":"B"},{"num":5,"test":"c"},{"num":1,"test":"D"}]
min_=min(list_,key=lambda x: x["num"])
min_ = min_["num"]
l=list(filter(lambda x: x["num"]==min_,list_))
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set min to an arbitrarily large number at the beginning of the program. I set it to 500. You then have to make you're checking if the "num" value is less than or equal to min, otherwise it will not grab both *1* values.

```
list = [{"num":1,"test":"A"},{"num":6,"test":"B"},{"num":5,"test":"c"},{"num":1,"test":"D"}]
min = 500
for x in list:
    if x["num"]<=min or min==None:
        min=x["num"]
        print(x)
print(min)
```